# image create photo, spaces in filename

Tags: tcl, filenames

This command is the problem:

```
set imageCreated [image create photo backPhoto -file $imageName]
```

It fails for spaces in the file name, even when they are escaped with backslash.

`aa-F-1s-ISO-2000.tiff`  works fine

`aa F 1s ISO-2000.tiff`  causes error

`aa\ F\ 1s\ ISO-2000.tiff` causes error

Is this a bug in image create or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks -
Peter

Comment: Filenames are strings, so you need quotes around the filename.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I guess you've got an `eval` somewhere…

Answer (score 1):

It should work fine, as demonstrated below. (I used ImageMagick's convert program to get a TIFF file from a png):

```
% package require Tk
8.6.5
% package require img::tiff
1.4.2
% set filename "Screenshot from 2015-10-22 23:54:41.png.tiff"
Screenshot from 2015-10-22 23:54:41.png.tiff
% set img [image create photo backPhoto -file $filename]
backPhoto
% # Just to confirm this is really a TIFF
% exec file $filename
Screenshot from 2015-10-22 23:54:41.png.tiff: TIFF image data, little-endian, direntries=15, height=65, bps=23594, compression=none, PhotometricIntepretation=RGB, orientation=upper-left, width=120
```

At this point we have the image created and it can be displayed using a Tk label widget. I can only assume your `imageName` variable doesn't really contain what you think.